# Why Spring Boot ignores configuration file inside its jar?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration

I have Spring Boot app with application-aficheDataProvider.yml in resources folder.

Content of application-aficheDataProvider.yml:

```
application:
  afiches:
    endpoints:
      - http://localhost:8080
```

That content mapped into config class

```
class AfichesConfiguration @ConstructorBinding constructor(
        val endpoints: Set<String>
)

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application")
class ApplicationConfiguration {
        @NestedConfigurationProperty
        lateinit var afiches: AfichesConfiguration
}
```

And fetched with SpEL

```
@Service
class AficheService @Autowired constructor(
        @Value("#{applicationConfiguration.afiches.endpoints}")
        endpoints: Collection<String>
)
```

I build my app, jar it (configuration file moved into jar archive) and launch it with profile aficheDataProvider.

[image]

But it throw exception:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Does it work just by running as a docker container outside of kubernetes?

Comment: In plain docker it works fine

Comment: You want to keep in resources and make it work or are you looking for an alternative?

Comment: I need to keep it in resources